# From classmethod to staticmethod: mypy complains for mixin but not inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, mixins, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

When I use inheritance, mypy doesn't complain when I change a `classmethod` into a `staticmethod`:

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls, a: int) -> int:
        return a

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def f(a: int) -> int:
        return a+1
```

However, if I'm using a mixin to do the same:

```py
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def f(a: int) -> int:
        return a+1

class D(C, A):
    pass
```

mypy gives the following error (on the `class D(C, A):` line):

> `Definition of "f" in base class "C" is incompatible with definition in base class "A"`

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was a bug fixed in mypy 0.710, probably by [#6720](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/6720).